Help gaining an Intuitive or Geometric understanding of Linear ODE solution
Working through Gilbert Strang differential equations and linear algebra to get a deeper understanding of ODEs and their solutions.
I came across the following explanation and I cannot understand it:

Each input $q(s) ds$ grows to $e^{a(t-s)}q(s) ds$ in the time between $s$ and $t$. Then the solution $y(t)$ comes from these inputs and growth factors $G=e^{a(t-s)}$. Add up (integrate) all those outputs = inputs times growth factors:
Gilbert Strang : " I like to think of each input growing by the factor $G(s,t)=e^{a(t-s)}$ in the time $t-s$.
Growing time for $q(s)$ is $t-s$ Ouput $y_p( t) =\int _{0}^{t} e^{a( t-s)} q( s) \ ds$

Does anyone have a better intuitive or geometric way of thinking about the solution to an linear ODE with an input ?
My current thoughts:

If I look at the particular solution like this instead : $y_p( t) =e^{at}\int _{0}^{t} e^{-as} q( s) \ ds$ and for simplicity consider the input a constant
I see two intervals here. The interval s where the input is on, where $e^{-s}$ is multiplied by my constant input and the result integrated to find my input.
I then view the multiplication of $e^{at}$ as the system dynamics influencing (decaying or growing) the input as soon as it turns on.

I do not understand why Gilbert Strang is saying the input growth time is $t-s$. If $s$ is the interval my input is on for, and $t$ is a later time, then $t-s$ has nothing to do with the growth of my input?
